# How do I kill a running background program with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a button in my program that when pressed, runs this line of code.

```
ps -eo pid,command | grep "test-usb20X" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
```

It gives me the correct pid output. For example, "3243".

What I want to do now is kill that pid. I would just write

```
exec("kill -9 3232");
```

But the pid changes, so how do I save that number to a variable and then use it in the kill line?

Answer (score 0):

You may write the response of your first command to a variable

```
$pid = exec("ps -eo pid,command | grep \"test-usb20X\" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'");
```

and use this variable for the next command

```
exec("kill -9 ".$pid);
```